# FME - How to merge geometries that they are in a distance of x meters?

Tags: fme-form, merge

I have a CAD file which I import in FME. I have two different geometries. A polygon and a point geometry. Each point geometry has some attributes which I want to pass to the polygon geometry. Both the points and the polygons have no id. So I can not merge based on the id.
I thought to use a "merge geometry in distance within" transformer.
Is there something like this?
For example: merge all the points and polygons which are in a distance of x into a big point (or polygon).

How do I do this in FME?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no single transformer for this. Instead you must use a combination of transformers.

- First, a **NeighborFinder**, setting the "Maximum Distance" to whatever you want the search distance to be.
- Pipe the points into one input, and the Polygons into the other; I don't believe in this case it should matter which.
- Enter a name for "Close Candidate List Name" too.
- The results that come out of MATCHED have found a matching point/polygon.
- These results should go into a **ListSorter** - sorting by the distance, numeric, increasing. This way you're finding the nearest candidate.
- Then use a **ListIndexer** on the list, using a List Index of 0. This gets the attributes of the nearest candidate and gives them to the base feature.

It's also possible to throw a FeatureMerger onto the end to then pull the geometry through too using the id of the feature you're now got via the NeighborFinder.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I will try this workflow. One more question. In what units I set the distance? I see there is measure tool in the inspector but where do I set the unit?

Comment: I believe they're whatever the units of the data projection are. The documentation confirms - http://docs.safe.com/fme/html/FME_Transformers/FME_Transformers.htm#Transformers/neighborfinder.htm "The maximum distance is measured in the units of coordinates of the input features."